# How to check for current active page in component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I would like to apply different styling to a component, for example i have a back icon here

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from '@ui-kitten/components';

export const BackIcon = () => (
    <Icon
    style={styles.icon}
    fill='#FFFFFF'
    name='arrow-back-outline'
    />
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 35,
    height: 35,
    bottom: 115,
    right: 145
  },
});
```

Currently I only have 1 style applied to it, but I would like to know you can detect the current active page so that when the user is in page A the icon will be styled differently as to when the component is called in page B for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as a prop from the parent component

```
    <Parent>
    
      <BackIcon current/>
      <BackIcon />
      <BackIcon />
    
    </Parent>
    
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    import { Icon } from '@ui-kitten/components';
    
    export const BackIcon = (props) => (
        <Icon
        style={props.current ? styles.activeIcon : styles.icon}
        fill='#FFFFFF'
        name='arrow-back-outline'
        />
    );
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      icon: {
        width: 35,
        height: 35,
        bottom: 115,
        right: 145
      },
    activeIcon:
    {
     color:'orange',
     width: 35,
     height: 35,
     bottom: 115,
     right: 145
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, quick question is there a way to pass in a variable to call a style? for example i set a new variable page will it be possible to use this variable to match the style? so like styles.page

Comment: @rwd , Could you explain more clear your question, i can help if i understand